# Not able to get text summary using HuggingFace transformers financial summary

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to summarize a text from a newsletter article from Yahoo Finance using Jupyter Notebook.

- I have updated my conda
- I installed conda install -c huggingface transformers
- I have installed conda install -c pytorch pytorch
- I have installed conda install -c conda-forge transformers
- I have installed conda install -c anaconda beautifulsoup4

Then I am importing the libraries:

```
      from transformers import PegasusTokenizer, 
      PegasusForConditionalGeneration
      from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
      import requests
```

Setting Summarization Model

```
      model_name = "human-centered-summarization/financial-summarization-pegasus"
      tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
      model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

Summarizing a Single Article:

```
      url = "https://au.finance.yahoo.com/news/china-restricting-tesla-use-uncovers-a- 
        enter code heresignificant-challenge-for-elon-musk-expert-161921664.html" 
       r = requests.get(url)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
       paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
```

However, when checking a single paragraph:

```
      paragraphs[0].text
```

'Thank you for your patience.'

```
     paragraphs[1].text
```

'Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.'

```
     paragraphs[2].text
```

---

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 paragraphs[2].text

IndexError: list index out of range

Where am I going wrong and how do I make it work properly to get the text summarization?

Comment: '`paragraph[0].text`' did you mean `paragraphs[0].text`?

Comment: Yes. I am editing it now!